# How can I extract studentized residuals from mixed model (lmer)?

Tags: r

Here is my model,

```
MY = lmer(MY ~ Energy*Protein + (1|Sequence/Cow) + (1|Period), data = CH4CO2)
```

Is there a function that can extract studentized residuals?

Comment: Thanks, I will look into it.

Comment: I don't think it's available out of the box, but `lme4` does have a `hatvalues.merMod()` method that should enable you to calculate them without *too* much difficulty ...

Comment: Maybe something like this would work:
`MYi <- influence(MY);
MYr <- residuals(MY);
MYs <- MYi$sigma;
MYh <- MYi$hat;
StudRes <- MYr / (MYs * (1-MYh)^.5`

Comment: Just FYI for passerby readers...Difference between residual types: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/22653/raw-residuals-versus-standardised-residuals-versus-studentised-residuals-what

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did according to the definition,

```
StudentResid = function(fit){
  res = residuals(fit)
  H = hatvalues(fit)
  sigma = summary(fit)$sigm
  sres = sapply(1:length(res), function(i) res[[i]]/(sigma*sqrt(1-H[[i]])))
  test = abs(sres) > 3
  ifelse(any(test), which(test), NA)
}

StudentResid(MY)
```

Here I return the observations that has a relatively large studentized residual, considering as outlier. Looks good?